# split command add "?" at the end of the file name

Tags: linux, bash

I'm using Linux split command to split  large file into multiple files, but unfortunately the output files comes with `?` character at the end, after the `.txt` extension.

Can you please help me to find out to remove it, or to force the output file name so that it doesn't contain it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please, provide a minimal working example or what have you tried so far. It's highly likely that you're messing up with the PREFIX.

Comment: We can't you fix this based on the information you have provided. Are your file names typical `ascii` chars, or are they some non-english language UTF8? Include one real filename that will generate the error for us AND include the exact command line you are using to try and split it. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe a file to the `sed` command, and substitute '\?' with a space or an empty char.
I did a `cat` on my file.txt:

```
abc?
123?
```

And then this:

```
cat file.txt | sed s/\?//g
```

and got:

```
abc
123
```

After the `sed`, the `s` says to substitute, the forward slash marks the start of the string to be found, the second slash separates that from the string to put in its place, the third slash marks the end of the new string (empty in this case), and the `g` says to do this globally.

This technique can be applied to your file names, most likely.  (I don't know what your script looks like).